# How to call object oriented javascript function from html

Tags: javascript, html, oop

I want call below code from HTML on event (right arrow key).

```
var Anim = function() {
var box = document.getElementById("square");
};
Anim.prototype.Start = function(event){
if(event.keyCode == 39){
    box.style.left = (box.offsetLeft + 100)+"px";
}
};
Anim.prototype.Stop = function(event){
if(event.keyCode == 37){
    box.style.left = (box.offsetLeft)+"px";
}
};
var Myanim = new Anim();
```

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="square" style="position: absolute;">This is my box</div>
```

Comment: Your `box` variable is local to the `Anim` constructor. Your  `Start` and `Stop` methods won't be able to access it. Maybe you wanted to [use a property](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13418980/1048572)?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery :

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
   alert('Handler for .keypress() called. - ' + event.charCode);
});
```

To import jquery in your project :

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

If you want to use Javascript only :

```
window.onkeydown = function (e) {
var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
if (code === 37) { //left key
    alert('up');
} else if (code === 40) { //down key
    alert('down');
}};
```

Comment: bt i only want to use javascript, no jquery